# For loop channel history Discord.py

Tags: python, for-loop, discord.py

I am having trouble trying to get a for loop to work here. There error I get when trying to run is `users =  await reaction.users() TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression`. I am pretty beginner at Async/Await. The goal of this code is to iterate through the reactions on messages in the 3 channels in the array. Any direction here would be greatly appreciated.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

if message.content == "/react":
            channel_ids= [12345, 67891, 12341]
            insert_query = "Insert into lnd_reaction (message_id, emoji, member_name, channel_id, active) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" 
            total = len(channel_ids)
            
            for i in range(total):
                channel = client.get_channel(channel_ids[i])
                async for msg in channel.history(limit=None):  
                    users = [] 
                    for reaction in msg.reactions:
                        users = await reaction.users()
                        for u in users:
                            if u != client.user.name:
                                print(msg.id, reaction, u, msg.channel, 1)
                                insert_values = (msg.id, str(reaction), str(u), msg.channel.id, 1)                        
                                try:
                                    cursor.execute(insert_query, insert_values)
                                    cnx.commit() 
                                except Exception as e:
                                    print("Error at:")
                                    print(e) 
                                    print("Exiting...")
                                    exit()
```

Comment: The title is about channel history, but your error says the problem is `reaction.users()`. Your channel history code is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reaction.users()` is a `generator`, not a function. You can't await it, but you have to loop over it.

Just like you're doing above for the `history`, you can use `async for` to loop over it.

```py
async for user in reaction.users():
    ...
```

More info in the Migration Guide: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#moving-away-from-custom-asynciterator

Also instead of manually parsing messages in `on_message`, consider using [`commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/index.html).

*PS instead of `for i in range(len(some_list))`, just use `for item in some_list`. It's a lot cleaner.*

Comment: Thank you! I made those changes and it works now. I was getting into slash commands, just wanted to get this functioning first. Appreciate the guidance!